# multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My question might be quite vague. I am looking for some reasonable approach to perform my task.
I have developed a webpage where the user uploads a file used as an input file for my code developed in python.

When the input  file is submitted through the webpage, it is saved in a temporary folder from where the daemon copies it to another location. What I want is to  looks for the files in the folder regularly (can write a daemon) If it finds more than one file it runs the code as separate jobs with the input files found in the directory limiting to a max of 5 processes running at the same time and when one process finishes it starts the next if there are files in the folder (in a chronological order).

I am aware of multiprocessing in python but don't know how to implement to achieve what I want or should I go for something like XGrid to mange my jobs. The code usually takes few hours to few day to finish one job. But the jobs are independent of each other.

Comment: I think you do not need multiprocessing *in* Python, but just spawning various Python processes concurrently, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to ask a question whose gist is "How do I do this general programming task?"  If you want help learning how to do a general programming task, ask a series of specific questions starting with whatever you're hung up on.  Note that this requires you to first read docs and attempt a start at your code.  When you get hung up on something specific, ask that specific question.

Comment: I have a code which I can run  it from command line giving inputfile  as an argument. I wanted some guidance and direction  before I attempt to write a code to do my job. I also wanted to make sure if I am thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I use a SQL table to perform such a thing, because my users may launch dozens of tasks alltogether if I do not limit them.

When a new file shows up, a daemon writes its name in the table (with allsort of other information such as size, date, time, user, ...)

Another daemon is then reading the table, getting the first not-executed task, doing it, and marking it as executed. When nothing is found to be done, it just waits for another minute or so.

This table is also the log of jobs performed and may carry results too. And you can get averages from it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have a mysql table with information about the job. I can add a column which stores the status of the job to monitor my jobs. Your help is much appreciated.